# Find the element using Selenium without XPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, wikipedia

I want to web scrape the data from Wikipedia about the annual passengers in US airports for 2019. This number can be accessed through airports pages here (the needed number is highlighted with pink):

[image]
I wrote this code which works for the Xpath of this particular element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
def search(link):
  driver = webdriver.Safari()
  driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/")
  elem = driver.find_element_by_name("search")
  elem.clear()
  elem.send_keys(link)
  elem.submit()
  time.sleep(3)
  elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[20]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/text()')
  num = elem1.text
  print(num)
  driver.close()
search('IND airport')
```

And it perfectly works! But only for this airport :( So I need to access this value from this table but for other airports also. Is there any alternative to Xpath? For example, if I need the data for JFK I need another Xpath which makes my code useless to use for a list of airports.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generalize this as much as possible, because different pages will have a different order of rows etc.

One way would be to get all table cells (*td*s, *th*s) and check if a cell contains Passengers, and if you're able to convert the following cell's value into an integer (which I assume all passenger counts will be).

```py
tcells = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.infobox th, .infobox td')

for i in range(len(tcells)):

    if 'Passengers' in tcells[i].text:
        try:
            x = int( tcells[i+1].text.split(' ')[0].split('[')[0].replace(',', '') )
            print(x)
            break
        except:
            continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `xpath` option.It will identify the Th tag with text contains `Passengers` and then `following-sibling::td`

```
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']//table/tbody//th[contains(.,'Passengers')]/following-sibling::td")
num = elem1.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get passengers data from this wikipedia site:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_busiest_airports_by_passenger_traffic

Will be more easy to scrape the data here instead to go to each wikipedia site.

Comment: It is only the list for the busiest airports, but I have some really small ones.